# Можно ли стилизовать dots в вертикальном скроллинге вот так?

Tags: css, вёрстка, прокрутка, pagination

[на этой странице](https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/#page1)

Есть боковая навигация. Как грамотно стилизовать активный круг, добавив высоту 60px и ширину 2px так, чтобы не покрывать другие неактивные круги?

То, как получается:
[image: плохо]

То, как нужно, чтобы было:
[image: хорошо]

Знает ли кто-нибудь?

Comment: Пока нашел только такое решение https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=2617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: space-around;
  width: 50px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #7c1f7c;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav_btn {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #d25fd2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav_title {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 0;
  width: 33px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.nav_btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.nav_btn:hover + .nav_title {
  visibility: visible;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_block">
  <div class="nav_btn"></div>
  <div class="nav_title">01</div>
  <div class="nav_btn"></div>
  <div class="nav_title">02</div>
  <div class="nav_btn"></div>
  <div class="nav_title">03</div>
  <div class="nav_btn"></div>
  <div class="nav_title">04</div>
  <div class="nav_btn"></div>
  <div class="nav_title">05</div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, если с ноля самому делать, но я спрашивал как это реализовать там, на странице, на которую я дал ссылку.